# Vanishing components of Kähler metric

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, cv.complex-variables, kahler-manifolds, differential-forms, kahler-ricci-flow

Let $(X, \omega) $ be a $n$-dimensional complex Kähler manifold such that $\omega^{n-1}=d\alpha $.

Does $\partial\alpha^{n-1,n-2} =0$ (resp. $\bar\partial\alpha^{n-2,n-1} =0$)
Where $\alpha^{n-1,n-2}$ is the (n-1,n-2)-component of $\alpha $?

Comment: If $n = 2$, then $\omega = d\alpha = \partial\alpha^{1,0} + (\bar{\partial}\alpha^{1,0} + \partial\alpha^{0,1}) + \bar{\partial}\alpha^{0,1}$. Given that $\omega$ has type $(1,1)$, we see that $\partial\alpha^{1,0} = 0$ and $\bar{\partial}\alpha^{0,1} = 0$. For $n > 2$, the same argument shows that $\partial\alpha^{n-1, n-2} + \bar{\partial}\alpha^{n, n-3} = 0$ and $\partial\alpha^{n-3, n} + \bar{\partial}\alpha^{n-2, n-1} = 0$.

Comment: Thank Michael, But i could not find any example such that $\partial \alpha^{n-1,n-2} \neq 0$